# Can't read <h3> class with my script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small issue. I can't seem to get the script to recognise the h3 tag. I can't just keep it as `h3`, I must add a class to it.

**Markup:**

```
<h3 class="jjheader">
    <?php echo $listitem->title ?>
</h3>
```

**CSS:**

```
#accordion h3.jjheader { 
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #666666;
    margin-top: 5px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #151515;
}
```

It works fine if I don't add a class to h3 and replace `.jjheader` with `h3` in the script below, however with the class, it doesn't.

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider('parentAccordion'); 
     parentAccordion.init('accordion','.jjheader',0,1,'accordion-selected');
</script>
```

The accordion is based on the TinyAccordion JavaScript Accordion package from http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/accordion/

Can someone please point in the right direction?

Comment: What the heck does `TINY.accordion.slider` do? If you use some sort of a plugin\framework, you should mention it's name and add a link the it's docs site.

Comment: updated with the framework name and site address

Comment: @gdoron - I think he is using TINY Accordion http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-accordion/index.html

Comment: @Derek. You deleted his link....

Comment: @gdoron - It is basically the same link, but his original link is the API's homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script starts out with defining `T$$`, which is only ever used in `init`. That function finds an element by tag name, within a container. It could easily be modified to use class selectors, for instance:

```
function T$$(e,p){
    if(e[0] == '.') {
       var matches = p.getElementsByClassName(e.substring(1));
       return matches.length == 0 ? null : matches[0];
    } else {
       return p.getElementsByTagName(e);
    }
}
```

The above code uses `getElementsByClassName` if the first character of the passed search string is a dot, indicating a css class selector; otherwise, it returns an element by tag name, as in the original source.

You could of course extend this, by checking for a leading `#` and doing `getElementById`, for instance. If you are already running jQuery on your site, you could simplify it and utilize jQuery's sizzle selector:

```
function T$$(e,p) { return $(p).find(e); }
```

Comment: thanks, this code works however it seems to remove the class when I click on each panel on the accordion. Any way of getting around this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about [this](http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/accordion/) script, you can't use a class name where you want to without modifying the code.  That is, the way it currently works, that second parameter to the "init" function must be a tag name.

That code is not pretty but it's simple, so enhancing it somehow to suit your needs shouldn't be too hard.